# Display Alert's button conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to display the button inside the Alert conditionally, on the value of the variable number.Here buttons is an Array which contains various buttons.

The code is based on typescript and Angular 6.

**.ts**

```
// all exports are done

export class XYZ {

    number: number;

    constructor() {}


    newMethod() {
    if(number ===0 || -ve) {
     // assign the button to the matchingAlert
    }

    } 

     private Alert(): void {

        this.matchingAlert =  {
          type: AlertType.Info,
          message: 'Hi',
          buttons: [
            //display this button conditionally on some value if number is -ve or 0       
           {
            label: 'Continue',
            type: AlertButtonType.Info,
            onClick: () => {
              // do the needful          
              });
            }
          }],
        };

      }
    }
```

Comment: `const buttons = [];` then `if (number === -ve || number === 0) buttons.push({ ... })` finally `this.matchingAlert = { ..., buttons, ... };`

Comment: I have updated my question..actually I wanted to call this function inside another function and there I have to assign the button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
// all exports are done

export class XYZ {

    number: number;

    constructor() {}

     private Alert(): void {

        const buttons = [];
        if (this.number > 3) {
          buttons.push({
            label: 'Continue',
            type: AlertButtonType.Info,
            onClick: () => {
              // do the needful          
              });
            });
        }

        this.matchingAlert =  {
          type: AlertType.Info,
          message: 'Hi',
          buttons: buttons,
        };

      }
    }
```

This is just one solution. There are several ways to achieve this, depending on how you want to scale it.

Edit: obviously I've guessed what the condition should be.

Edit 2:

Updated to call from another function

```
export class XYZ {

    number: number;

    constructor() {}

     private Alert(): void {        
        this.matchingAlert =  {
          type: AlertType.Info,
          message: 'Hi',
          buttons: []
        };

      }
    }

    private methodToAddButtons(): void {
        if (this.number > 3) {
          this.matchingAlert.buttons.push({
            label: 'Continue',
            type: AlertButtonType.Info,
            onClick: () => {
              // do the needful          
              });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wanted to call this from another function and push the button inside that function

Comment: I've made a guess how you might want to do this in an update to the post, but I'd need more information about what you're trying to achieve to help more